# How to re-generate .keystore file from keystore password

Tags: android

I accidentally deleted my app's `.keystore` file, but I still have the Keystore password used to generate the .keystore file.
Is there any way to recover that file using the password?

Comment: looks like you have lost the .keystore. So SAD

Answer (score 3):

**No Its not possible** . Once you lost it you can't generate same.
You have to create new one.

Comment: So sad :/. Thanks

Comment: Yes.Its sad part . But its never late .

Comment: I got this, I think it's possible now, `You can update your app using new keystore file ,you need to enable google play app signing on play store console `,https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

Comment: It's just a way to manage your keys, but still, if you do it on your own. The situation will remain same.